# What attributes are bound statically vs dynamically

Tags: variable-binding

I am having a hard time understanding the concept of what attributes get bound statically instead of dynamically.  Below is code and from that code, what gets bound statically?

Here is an example (In C):

`static int count = getRand(0, 100); // getRand is a library`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert of C/linkers/binding but I'm not sure to understand what you mean with the code you provided. Static binding versus dynamic binding is very different and it has nothing to do with the `static` keyword in C++. C has no dynamic binding "out of the box". See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420628/what-are-static-and-dynamic-binding-in-c-strictly-c-not-c.

The static keyword in C makes the variable appear in the data segment of the executable. It will be global to all functions and will be accessed using a relative offset from RIP by default. It can also be called using an absolute address. For example, look at the following code:

```
class A{
    public:
    static int var;
};

int main(){
    A::var = 4;
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles to

```
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    $4, A::var(%rip)
    movl    $0, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

In particular the line `$4, A::var(%rip)` accesses the variable A::var as an offset relative to RIP (the instruction pointer). In this case, I think only the symbol is kept because the address of A::var will be determined by the linker after compilation. On Linux, the ELF executable has a symbol table and it will have a symbol defined for A::var. I don't remember well the exact structure of ELF files so I can't tell how it is done exactly. Basically the symbol will be resolved by the linker to have the right offset from RIP.

Now, as to dynamic vs static binding, this is done via the `virtual` keyword in C++. It is really a matter of resolving symbols at runtime instead of at compile/link time (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=only-virtual-functions-c).

For example, on the link I provide you have this code (that I modified a bit):

```
class A {
   void f() {  }
};

class B: public A {
   void f() { }
};

void g(A& arg) {
   arg.f();
}

int main() {
   B x;
   g(x);
}
```

It compiles to (in Intel syntax):

```
A::f():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
g(A&):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    A::f()
        nop
        leave
        ret
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        lea     rax, [rbp-1]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    g(A&)
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

In the g() function the A::f() is called instead of B::f(). It is often not the desired behaviour because we inherited the class and would like that the compiler resolves that we want to call the inherited class override of the function. This is often called polymorphism in C++. We pass a reference to B in the g(A&) function and would like that the compiler still call the B::f() function by determining the type of the object referenced instead of using the type of the reference itself.

This cannot be done at compile time because the type of the reference passed to the g() function is not known yet. In static binding (without the `virtual` keyword on A::f()), the compiler simply assumes you are calling A::f() and blindly calls it.

If you add the `virtual` keyword on A::f():

```
class A {
    public:
        virtual void f() {  }
};

class B: public A {
    public:
        void f() { }
};

void g(A& arg) {
   arg.f();
}

int main() {
   B x;
   g(x);
}
```

The g() function changes to this:

```
g(A&):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    rdx
        nop
        leave
        ret
```

It will resolve the right function to call based on the type of the object referenced passed to it. It will find that using some tables somewhere. I apologize that I don't have more information on how it is done. Maybe someone else can help with that.

For info, I compile the code with https://godbolt.org if you want to have a look. For the rest of the stuff in the different functions I show see my answer here: [What are pointers in low-level language like C](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/145305/what-are-pointers-in-low-level-language-like-c/145308#145308)